# スクロール時の、UITableViewのハイライトを中止したい。

Tags: swift, ios, xcode, uitableview

お世話になります。

画面をなぞってUITableViewをスクロールする時に、触ったセルがチカッと選択色でハイライトされるのですが、スクロールの場合については、このハイライトを中止する方法はありませんか？

タップして画面遷移する時は通常通りに、選択白が表示されるようにしたいです。